# Check if string contains substring, but not at the end

Tags: delphi

Is there a built-in function in delphi to find if a string contains a substring, but **not** at the end?

For example suppose I have these strings:

```
G15001,
G15005,
G15015,
G14015,
G14004,
PLU15010,
PLU14015
```

I want to return true  when string is G15001 G15005,G15015,PLU15010 and substring to search is 15, but return false when  G14015 or PLU14015 because they have  15 only at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Pos` to check if the substring can be found. Then check that the substring is not located at the end.

```
function ContainsBeforeEnd(const str, substr: string): Boolean;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  P := Pos(substr, str);
  if P = 0 then
    // substr not found at all
    Result := False
  else
    // found, now check whether substr is at the end of str
    Result := P + Length(substr) - 1 <> Length(str);
end;
```

Comment: If it is heavy used, maybe he can use PosEx, which is faster and allow to start the search from a specified offset.

Comment: @RBA I think Pos is implemented as a call to PosEx. The search needs to start at the beginning of the string, as I read the question. The code could also be written with string helpers.

Comment: In pre-XE3, you can use `StrUtils.EndsText()` or `StrUtils.RightStr()`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Your one-liner won't work as the OP wants. Why? Because it will mark any string that ends with certain sub-string invalid even if they do contain that specific sub-sting somewhere in the middle. So the correct answer is your first code example.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thank you, you are quite right. I have removed that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau EndsText and RightStr won't help because he needs to find strings that contain the substring not at the end.

Comment: @dummzeuch: I'm aware of the OP's requirement to ignore a matching substring on the end of the string.  I was merely suggesting `EndsText()`/`RightStr()` in response to an earlier suggestion of using `TStringHelper.EndWith()`, which does not exist prior to XE3.

Answer (score 0):

This one liner should give you what you want:

```
Pos(substr,copy(str,1,length(str)-1))>0
```

David's solution is cleaner, but I just wanted to do a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

More suggestions with emphasis on one-liners:

```
function ContainsBeforeEnd(const str, substr: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (Pos(subStr,Str) in [0,Length(str)-Length(subStr)+1]);
end;

function ContainsBeforeEnd(const str, substr: string): Boolean;
begin // Note, string helpers returns results based on zero based strings
  Result := (Length(str) > Length(subStr) and 
    (str.IndexOf(subStr) in [0..Length(str)-Length(subStr)-1]);
end;
```